# Django csv download performance issue

Tags: python, django, csv

Ok so i am having problems generating a CSV file from data.

I have a list of about 6,000 objects. These objects are like custom forms, 
so each object has many fields associated with it. for example a request could consist of name, age, phone number, etc. In this case every request has the same fields. So each form has a one to many relationship with these fields.

So I am grabbing this custom form and a few standard things from it as a ValuesQuerySet, then grabbing all of the fields associated with this form. and adding them to each row. Finally I use dictionary writer to write the data to a csv. This all works great however the performance is awful. to do my 6,000 records each with about 15 custom fields takes about 90 seconds.(This triggers a timeout error). I am in need of some way to make this faster.

My Code Looks Something like this....

```
forms = SomeForm.objects.filter(created_by=user).values('value1', 'value2', 'etc...')
for form in forms:
     id = form['id']
     fields = Fields.objects.filter(Form_id=id).values('value', 'field__label')
     for field in fields:
         label = field['form_field__label']
         value = field['value']
         form[label] = value
writer = csv.DictWriter(response, fieldnames=fieldnames)
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(forms)
```

Some of the code is removed, but this is the gist of it.
if you can think of anyway to speed this up or maybe an alternative way to handle it i would be very grateful.

Comment: Have you tried trying to make the `created_by` field an index? That might increase the performance...

Comment: Ya, that was one of the things i thought of. After a bit of research, in django when you define a model with a foreign key it automatically sets db_index=True. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Just in case you didn't notice, django has `select_related` and `prefetch_related` functions on queryset that could load some relationships in one query and put them in the queryset cache. Maybe that would help a little.

Comment: This is no trivial task anyways and any processing with that amount of records should be better in a celery task

Comment: As Alvaro says, this is not something that you should do in a request. Check celery and run it as an async task, once it is done you can notify the user about the location of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Ya I ended up taking taking cdvv7788's advice and making this a celery task. Thanks guys